# How do I get the windows 8 media visual to appear using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

I'm looking for a way to make the media visual appear.

Just to clarify, i'm talking about that black box that appears on the top left that has the volume control (or other music controls when the music app is running) in windows 8 - that appears when you press a media key (like volume/up down or next/prev track).

I want to make it appear, using c#, without changing anything - for instance I can inject a volume up/down key pressed but that would actually change the volume... so that's not a solution...

I don't know exactly what its called so I'm having a hard time finding any information about it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 see,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.aspx

For Windows 8.1:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.aspx

Comment: This could be what I'm looking for, still trying to find the specific call that will do this.

Comment: Also - this is for Windows Store Apps, I'm not sure if this applies to WPF